# For loop in node.js returns undefined every time whenever i access the elements with it

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I am a beginner to Node js.I have created an "blogs.ejs" where ,the page contains posts that are posted by the respective logged in user.So, here i have added a anchor tag ,which when pressed the respective post get deleted.I have to do this whithout reloading the page.So i have used fetch method inorder to send post request to my backend.My fetch method works fine,but every time i click the delete button i am encountering an error.So i tried to console log it.And it is not logging the output.
I dont know what mistake i have done.

blogs.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css" />
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex-box">
        <div class="nav-content"> Welcome <%= user.name %></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div class="nav-content"><a href="/home/<%= user._id %>">Home</a></div>
            <div class="nav-content"><a href="/myblogs/<%= user._id %>">My blogs</a></div>
            <div class="nav-content"><a href="/addblogs/<%= user._id %>">Add blog</a></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <p class="user_id" style="display:none"><%= user._id %></p>
            <h2 class="blog-name">My Blogs</h2>
        </div>
        <br>
        
        <% if(blogs.length!=0){ %>
            <% blogs.forEach(blog=>{ %>
                <div class="blog-content">
                    <div class="blog">
                        <a  class="delete" data-doc="<%= blog._id %>">Delete</a>
                        <p class="id" style="display:none ;"><%= blog._id %></p>
                        <h3><%= blog.title %></h3>
                        <p><%= blog.post %></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br><br>
            <% }) %>
        <% }else{%>
            <h3>No blog Posts</h3>
        <% } %>
        <br><br>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        const deleted =document.querySelectorAll('a.delete');
            for(var i=0;i<deleted.length;i++){
                deleted[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
                    // Accessing post id
                    var id=document.getElementsByClassName('id')[i].innerHTML;
                    const usr_id=document.getElementsByClassName('user_id')[0].innerHTML;
                    console.log("In script tag: post id is "+id)
                    const url='/delete';
                        customHeaders = { "Content-Type": "application/json", }
                        let data={
                            post_id:id,
                            usr_id:usr_id
                        };
                        fetch(url,{
                            method:'POST',
                            body:JSON.stringify(data),
                            headers:customHeaders,
                        }).then((res) =>{
                            res.json();
                            console.log("Method passed")
                        })
                        .then((data)=>{
                            console.log(data);
                        })
                        .catch((err) => 
                            console.log(err))
                        })
            }
    </script>

    
    
</body>
</html>
```

This is my routes.js file:

```
    router.post('/delete',async(req,res)=>{
        const id=req.body.id;
        const user=req.body.usr_id;
        console.log("In routes.js: post id is "+id);
        try{
            await Post.deleteOne({_id:id});
            console.log("deleted");
            res.json({redirect:'/'})

        }
        catch(err){
           console.log(err);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure which part is returning undefined but I think it could be the 2nd then statement in your fetch. the reason is that you didn't return anything in your 1st then statement. Also in your console, you need to be more descriptive especially since you're using it for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging steps:

#### Which console.log statement is saying that `id` is undefined?

You are console.logging it in two places.

I suggest amending the console.log in the script tag to:

```
console.log("In script tag: post id is "+id)
```

And the one in the routes.js to :

```
console.log("In routes.js: post id is "+id)
```

Then please tell us what each message is saying.

#### Perhaps you could specify the blog id when calling the deletion function?

```
       <% if(blogs.length!=0){ %>
            <% blogs.forEach(blog=>{ %>
                <div class="blog-content">
                    <div class="blog">
                        <button  class="delete" onclick="deleteBlogById('<%= blog._id %>')">Delete</a>
                        <p class="id" style="display:none ;"><%= blog._id %></p>
                        <h3><%= blog.title %></h3>
                        <p><%= blog.post %></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br><br>
            <% }) %>
        <% }else{%>
            <h3>No blog Posts</h3>
        <% } %>
```

Then your deletion function can be simpler, for example:

```
function deleteBlogById(id) {

  const usr_id = document.getElementsByClassName('user_id')[0].innerHTML;
  console.log("in deleteBlogById, post id is " + id)
  const url = '/delete';
  customHeaders = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
  let data = {
    post_id: id,
    usr_id: usr_id
  };
  fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: customHeaders,
    }).then((res) => {
      res.json();
      console.log("Method passed")
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) =>
      console.log(err))
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.But in my case, i need a addEventListener method which should check for a click and when a click is made the data should be send to the backend .At the same time the post placed in that particular div should be deleted("The div with a class name 'blog'").In my case whenever i try to click i am getting error in my console saying "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML')"

Comment: Why would you _need_ to add an event listener? It is an awkward way to do it. Why not make a reproducible example, i.e. one that runs here in the browser using the `<>` icon above the text entry box.